# how to install boost_python-py38 on ubuntu system

Tags: boost-python

I used cmake to build my project. I tried `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, but it didn't solve my issue. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What did the log say ?

Comment: CMake error at /usr/share/cmake-*/Moudles/FinBoost.cmake:1947 (message):Unable to find the requested boost libraries, boost version 1.65.1 could not find the following static boost libraries: boost_python-py38

Comment: could try `sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev`  and the library is `lboost_python38`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and found that the needed library was installed under the name `/usr/lib/<arch>/libboost_python38.so` (for x86_64 in my case that's `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so`).

So I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py38.so` and was able to link OK.

I ran into this specifically when trying to install `pygattlib` under python 3.8.